# Getting mysql database size using java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have an online MySQL database and i upload data into it using a java program.But every-time before inserting the data into the database i want to check if database is empty or not.And if it is empty how much bits are available so that i could compare it with the file(whose size i know before hand)which i have to upload.
NOTE:- Total database size is 5MB

I taught of using ResultSet class with "Select * from table" and get the size of object returned by result set.But it seems ResultSet does not provide any such method to achieve it.Please help me out .

Comment: You can either check on your database provider documentation how to achieve this, if not you should've set threshold for number of rows.

Comment: actually i dont't want to limit the number of rows i just want to upload maximum number of files i can.And each file has a variable size

Comment: Why do you want to check if database is empty or not? Do you mean table? Can you show the code.

Comment: I don't want to check whether the database is empty or not i want to see whether it has sufficient space to upload an upcoming file.

Comment: Databases do complicated things to store data, which means it's not easily predictable how much space will be used for storing particular items.

Comment: To be more clear my program capture screen shots at regular interval and stores it into database but when the database is filled fully it should not upload that screenshot and stores it as a file on the host machine and when the database again have sufficient space it should upload it again.

Comment: i don't want to know how much space will be used to store a particular item i just want to know what is the current size of my whole database.

Answer (score 3):

```
String sql = "SELECT table_schema AS "Database", 
ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Size (MB)" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema;";
ResultSet resultSet;
PreparedStatement statement = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
resultSet= statement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString("Database") " | " + resultSet.getString("Size (MB)"));
}
```